# How do I annotate my XML to remove the parent node of an array in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, annotations

I have an integration that I need to follow a certain pattern of XML.

One of the requirements is something like this...

```
<Telecom>
    <TeleType>Mobile</TeleType>
    <TeleNumber>806-611-1111</TeleNumber>
    <TeleType>Home</TeleType>
    <TeleNumber>806-411-9111</TeleNumber>
    <TeleType>Other</TeleType>
    <TeleNumber>806-311-1111</TeleNumber>
</Telecom>
```

I've set up my model to look like this:

```
[XmlArray("Telecom")]
[XmlArrayItem(typeof(Phone))]
public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
```

and

```
[XmlRoot("Telecom")]
public class Phone
{
    [XmlElement("TeleType")]
    public string PhoneType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TeleNumber")]
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

However, the output I receive is:

```
<Telecom>
    <Phone>
        <TeleType>HOME</TeleType>
        <TeleNumber>801-555-1234</TeleNumber>
    </Phone>
    <Phone>
        <TeleType>WORK</TeleType>
        <TeleNumber>801-123-4321</TeleNumber>
    </Phone>
</Telecom>
```

How do I remove the Phone node from this and render the first example?

Note: using

```
[XmlElement("Telecom")]
public List<MICAPhone> Phones { get; set; }
```

doesn't work either as I get multiple Telecom nodes.

Comment: The output You receive makes more sense than the one You want to achieve :)

Comment: Agreed... If only I had control over this request.  But I'm integrating with a 3rd party.

Comment: ok give me a second I'll open VS and try it out :)

Comment: You will always have 3pair of teleType/teleNumber or it can be one for instance ?

Comment: There is no limit to how many.  0-*.

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the solution using Linq to xml, I hope You can go this way. Please see below:

```
// You will have to use System.Xml.Linq library
public class Phone // the only class I have
{
    public string PhoneType { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

public XElement CreateTelecomNode(List<Phone> phones)
{
    var telecom = new XElement("Telecom");
    foreach (var item in phones)
    {
        telecom.Add(new XElement("TeleType", item.PhoneType));
        telecom.Add(new XElement("TeleNumber", item.Number));
    }
    return telecom;
}
```

Output with example list:

[image: outputExample]